Palatini variation of Ricci tensor
I was looking at Problem 2 of chapter 4 of Sean Carroll's General Relativity book, where you were supposed to demonstrate starting from the Einstein-Hilbert action, and assuming that the connection is symmetric on the two lower indices, that it is the Christoffel (Levi-Civita) action. The idea is to use Palatini's formalism, and calculate the variation of the action with respect to the connection instead of the metric, as one usually does. Carroll also suggests to split the connection as such:
$$ \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu}=\tilde{\Gamma}^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu} + C^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu}$$
Where the first term in the right hand side is the Christoffel connection and the second is just some tensor. You are somehow supposed to demonstrate that that tensor vanishes. The problem is that I can't figure out how to correctly vary the Ricci tensor with respect to the connection, because derivatives of the variation appear, and I can't throw them away, since as it says in the text, Stokes' theorem doesn't work for an arbitrary covariant derivative, but I also don't know exactly how I'm supposed to act with covariant derivatives on connections anyways. So how should I proceed?
